# How to change the default log file name and/or location for PhantomJS in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webdriver-io

My test suite uses *WebdriverIO* and *WDIO* as the runner to run tests against *PhantomJS*.

The default location for the `phantomjsdriver.log` file is the root of the project.

There is an option in `wdio.conf.js` to pass command line arguments to *PhantomJS*:

```
const profiles = {
  default: {
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    seleniumLogs: 'logs',
    capabilities: [
      {
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.binary.path': phantomjsPath, // Set elsewhere
        'phantomjs.cli.args': [
          '--debug=true',
          '--webdriver-logfile=/project/new/path/phantomjsdriver.log'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

This results in the following in *selenium-standalone.txt*:

```
17:03:29.589 INFO - arguments: [--debug=true, --webdriver-logfile=/project/new/path/phantomjsdriver.log, --webdriver=33837, --webdriver-logfile=/project/phantomjsdriver.log]
```

Note that the first `--webdriver-logfile` value is the one I set, the second is the default which I'm trying to overwrite.

How can I stop that second one being included?